# issues with mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I installed django using following commands

```
cd Django-1.4.1
sudo python setup.py install
cd
mkdir testing
cd testing
django-admin.py
django-admin.py startproject demo
cd demo
python manage.py runserver
```

and Msql-python using

```
pip install MySQL-python
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install MySQL-python
```

and still getting the error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Comment: What happens if you open a python process from the command line and import MySQLdb?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have installed `mysql-python` both with `pip` and from the repository. I'm not sure if it's related though.

Comment: May be a silly question, but do you have MySQLdb installed (sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb)?

Comment: Is Django running from internal http server (by manage.py) or from within Apache context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See as Mike johnson said first check  MySQLdb is really installed in your system or not

if not  then use

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

make sure it should installed properly

or you can use another alternative like `easy_install`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce that problem on my Debian box and:

1. Navigated to /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6
2. Ran a command: chmod go-rx MySQLdb
3. On the other console, did:

   > > > import MySQLdb
   > > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
   > > >         File "", line 1, in 
   > > >       ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

I suppose it might be something with rights management on your system (I had this issue on some RHEL server just a week ago).

What you might want to do (if it's not Debian):
1. Login as root.
2. Type:

```
# find / -name "MySQLdb"
```

1. Navigate to directory that find finds (in my case it was /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6).
2. Type:

   chmod -R go+rx MySQLdb
3. Test on not-elevated console if importing MySQLdb from Python and regular user context works.